# Is it common to write a lot of code under if __name__ == '__main__': statement

Tags: python

my current coding style is like

```
import xxx

def fun1()
def fun2()
...

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    task = sys.argv[1]
    if task =='task1':
        do task1
    elif task == 'task2':
        do task2
    ...
```

my problem is that the part of the code under

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

is quite huge comparing to the functions defined above and I was told this is not a good programming style. It is due to the fact that I modify stuff and do experiment in each tasks frequently and I want to separate those part of the code away from functions which are less likely to be modified. I want to learn more advice here, thanks!

Comment: It's better to wrap it all up into a single `main()` function, then call this function under your `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: I agree with BusyAnt, define a main() and do it there because if  `__name__ == __main__`  only gets called if this is the main routine, so on import it won't ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like BusyAnt said, the common way to do it is

```
import xxx

def fun1()
def fun2()
...



def main():
    task = sys.argv[1]
    if task =='task1':
        do task1
    elif task == 'task2':
        do task2
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The upside of this is it does not run on `import`, but `main()` can still be run from another module or file if so preferred.

Comment: Thanks for quoting @Uzzee, I was actually writing an answer from it myself. :)

Comment: Say this file is named `script1.py` and if we import it to another file called `script2.py`, the ``__name__`` variable will not equal to `'__main__'` but to `'script1'`, and therefore `main()` will not be run by default. We can however choose to run it by typing `script1.main()` in our script2.py file.

Answer (score 3):

**It is not forbidden** to write a lot of things under `if __name__ == '__main__'`, though it is considered better and more readable to **wrap everything up in a `main()` function**. This way, the code in `main()` isn't executed when you `import` this module in another module, **but** you can still choose to run it, by calling `imported_script.main()`.

Your code would then look like this :

```
import xxx

def fun1()
def fun2()
...


def main():
    task = sys.argv[1]
    if task =='task1':
        do task1
    elif task == 'task2':
        do task2
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I encourage you to read about what does this `if` statement do, [among the many questions asked about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/5018771).